# selecting total comments (pos & neg) + latest comment for each

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am writing a query to get the top 10 rated businesses, the number of positive comments for each business, the number of negative comments for each business and the latest comment for each of these businesses.

```
SELECT comment.bis_id, Sum( Case When comment.rating <= 2 Then 1 Else 0 End ) As NegVotes
, Sum( Case When comment.rating >= 4 Then 1 Else 0 End ) As PosVotes, bis.bis_name
FROM bis, comment
WHERE comment.bis_id = bis.bis_id
GROUP BY bis_id
ORDER BY PosVotes DESC
LIMIT 0, 10";
```

The above gets positive comments and negative comments, but I can't seem to work out how to get the latest comment as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  c.bis_id
  , Sum( Case When c.rating <= 2 Then 1 Else 0 End ) As NegVotes 
  , Sum( Case When c.rating >= 4 Then 1 Else 0 End ) As PosVotes
  , b.bis_name 
  , cc.last_comment
FROM bis b
INNER JOIN comment c on (c.bis_id = b.bis_id)
INNER JOIN (SELECT c2.bis_id, c2.comment_text as last_comment 
            FROM comment c2
            GROUP BY c2.bis_id
            HAVING c2.comment_date = MAX(c2.comment_date) ) cc 
        ON (cc.bis_id = b.bis_id)          
GROUP BY b.bis_id 
ORDER BY PosVotes DESC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: great response, thank you. I think it should be GROUP BY c2.bis_id. I also had to change line 9 to:

INNER JOIN (SELECT c2.bis_id, c2.comment_date, c2.comment_text as last_comment 

But after that it doesn't seem to work as expected - it excludes most businesses from the query. Seems to work fine when I change the HAVING clause to c2.comment_date = MIN (c2.comment_date).

Any ideas??